# Crystal report Parameter Fetching Data from DB

Tags: crystal-reports-2013, dynamicparameters

How can I add a parameter to fetch customer names from a database in Crystal Reports 2013?

Is it possible to write a query in a formula to retrieve the data?

I have already used dynamic parameters, but they don't allow for searching. I also need to attach this report to SAP. Here is a sample of how the report is currently fetching data.

I tried dynamic parameters and it's fetching values but it's not query-based. I also want to fetch results when there is nothing selected so it should give all result.

Here is what I am getting:

[image: Crystal Reports parameters]

Here is what I am expecting:

[image: Crystal Reports parameters]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking but my guess is that you need to use an ***Optional Parameter*** in combination with the ***HasValue()*** function.
If you Google these terms you'll fins explanations and examples.

If that was not the issue, please try to clarify the question. Perhaps use the simplest possible clear example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand the question. But now my guess is that you need to increase the maximum nuber of values a dynamic parameter retrieves.

Here are the key points from SAP's document about this: https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1270986
**1270986 - How to modify the maximum number of values available in a dynamic parameter list for a 64 bit terminal?**

- Crystal Reports 2011 Release

Create a registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV.
Add a string value "MaxRowsetRecords" and set the value to the maximum number of values that you desire for your report. For example, a value of 2000 will return up to 2000 values in the lowest level of a cascading parameter.
After making changes to the registry, restart the affected service or application as required.

- Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010

Create a registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV.
Add a string value "MaxRowsetRecords" and set the value to the maximum number of values that you desire for your report. For example, a value of 2000 will return up to 2000 values in the lowest level of a cascading parameter.
After making changes to the registry, restart the affected service or application as required.